# How to auto-scroll to location of git hash commit on git tree on CLI

Tags: git

### Background

I normally stick to git cli for all my git operations. The only time I use a git gui tool is when i want to see the location of a git commit relative to the tree.

Right now I have this command line that shows me the git tree:

```
git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all
```

which shows me a nice tree illustration:

```
* 6068f4b (origin/develop) exclude arm64 architecture
* d49b4be Fix crash for global mark jump in Xcode12
*   6e32166 Merge branch 'master' into develop
|\
| * 6356710 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) README.md
* | b126142 update project
* | 3b050e5 Failing Unit Test is commented out with FIXME comment addition
* | caad84d improve test
* |   0bc3054 Merge branch 'master' into develop
|\ \
| |/
| * a4a4fdb Fix Yank
* |   39d38ce Merge pull request #308 from chml/fix/yankAndPut
|\ \
```

### Problem

The problem is that if i want to see the *location* of a git hash in this tree, I have to do the following:

- run `git checkout <target-hash>`
- run `git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all`
- scroll on the git tree manually for a while until i see where `HEAD` is pointing to (this can take a while for git repos that are years old)
- switch back to my original commit `git checkout <original-commit>`

### Question

I would like a command that would make all these steps into one (so I should avoid changing my git HEAD commit). For git GUI's that's a pretty straight forward operation (both gitkraken and sourcetree offer that out of the box). For example in sourcetree this is a *jump to commit* operation:

[image]

Suggestions?

Comment: `git log <your flags> | grep -C 7 HEAD`

Comment: @AlexLarionov where does the `<target-hash>` go in your command?

Comment: instead of `HEAD`, this is the seach pattern, and `-C 7` flag means how many lines to context around to show

Comment: If you use a pager, there’s `<command> | less -p <target-hash>`. Not sure how to do it with terminal emulators, though. It may be implementation-specific.

Comment: The pager used by git is generally `less`, which has an integrated search function : type `/`, then `<target-hash>`, then `[enter]`. Is this the kind of answer you are looking for ?

Comment: @AlexLarionov your command only works if HEAD doesn't require paging (ie if it's a recent head).. so for example whereas this command `git la | grep -C 7 f88305af24` returns nothing, `git show f88305af24` works just fine

Comment: @abbood check the comment under this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/288231) then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do it in bash, open `.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`

`vim ~/.bashrc`

let's create an alias for the git command you use at first, so you don't have to keep typing it

```
alias gitTree="git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all"
```

Now, let's write a function that shows the head

```
function gshow(){
    git checkout "$1" --quiet
    git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all | grep "(HEAD)"
    git checkout - --quiet
}
```

close  the file, and run this from the terminal `source ~/.bashrc` or  `source ~/.bash_profile`

now you call it from the terminal

```
gshow <target-hash>
```

I added the `--quiet` command so it only shows you what you want to see, and when done, it returns to the previous branch.

## update

I updated the script to make it default to showing a 10 line context, but that 10 line can be expanded in case the user wants more context:

```
function gshow(){
    ARG2=${2:-10}
    git checkout "$1" --quiet
    git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all | grep -C $ARG2 "(HEAD)"
    git checkout - --quiet
}
```

example usage:

### with no context arg

```
$ gshow 0bc3df2
|\ \ \
| * | | dff86b7 Add an FAQ on why users need to resign Xcode to use Xvim2
| | |/
| |/|
* | |   d267b5f Merge pull request #173 from 99arobe/task/update-README-to-remove-dead-link
|\ \ \
| |/ /
|/| |
| * | 64ecb94 Remove contributing guidelines from the README
|/ /
* | 0bc3df2 (HEAD) add comment
* | 2bddec1 add header update command comment
* | e244543 update Xcode10 beta3 header
* |   763b317 Merge branch 'master' into develop
|\ \
| |/
| *   2e50b5a Merge pull request #154 from rick-kilgore/master
| |\
| | * fc3eb9c fudge for the lines that might be only partially shown
| | * 62efd89 move logic into switch for XVIM_SCROLL_TYPE_LINE
| | * c4da83f allow scrolling to the first and last lines.  ensure cursor is in the right place
```

### with context arg

```
$ gshow 0bc3df2 20
|\ \ \
| |/ /
| * | ad28881 update branches and release readme
* | | 07d6820 deployment target 10.12 -> 10.13, swift -> 4.0
* | |   b06fbdf Merge pull request #177 from timothycosta/develop
|\ \ \
| * | | 2c48bcf Implemented 'source' command
| * | | 98cf07d Source xvimrc on toggle xvim
|/ / /
* | |   c725592 Merge pull request #175 from 99arobe/task/update-README-to-include-reasons-for-resigning-Xcode
|\ \ \
| * | | dff86b7 Add an FAQ on why users need to resign Xcode to use Xvim2
| | |/
| |/|
* | |   d267b5f Merge pull request #173 from 99arobe/task/update-README-to-remove-dead-link
|\ \ \
| |/ /
|/| |
| * | 64ecb94 Remove contributing guidelines from the README
|/ /
* | 0bc3df2 (HEAD) add comment
* | 2bddec1 add header update command comment
* | e244543 update Xcode10 beta3 header
* |   763b317 Merge branch 'master' into develop
|\ \
| |/
| *   2e50b5a Merge pull request #154 from rick-kilgore/master
| |\
| | * fc3eb9c fudge for the lines that might be only partially shown
| | * 62efd89 move logic into switch for XVIM_SCROLL_TYPE_LINE
| | * c4da83f allow scrolling to the first and last lines.  ensure cursor is in the right place
| | * 17ab836 don't move cursor on ctrl-e, ctrl-y
| |/
* | 7f4943d update the mangled signature of addSelectedRange
* | ac3faea fix #161 Xcode 10: Crash while edit in 'build phases'
* | 7dc4ea9 fix #158 not work C-f,C-b,C-u,C-d in Xcode10
* | 6397eff improve swift source
* | 9415303 add logger for swift
* | dae173f change swift function pointer address for Xcode10
* | d95e598 change from Xcode9.3 header to Xcode10
* | da8b31d class-dump Xcode10
```

Comment: i updated your answer, I hope you don't mind (I gave you the correct answer all the same)

Comment: @abbood, Of course, I don't :) That makes the answer even better! Thank you so much!

Comment: It's a pleasure man :) with your answer I'm not using a git gui again in my life!